# Center a `tabular` table despite it overflowing the page slightly

Tags: tables, luatex, margins, boxes

I want to put a really large table (which is just ever-so-slightly larger than the normal page content) in the center of the page.

Centering works well when the content fits, but I'd like to "squeeze" the slightly too-large table into the center of the page.

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}  
  % A table with 20+ columns goes here, displaying single- to two-digit numbers
  \begin{tabular}[pos]{r|cccccccccccccccccccc}
    1x & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 10 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Lots of numbers}
  \label{tab:numbers}
\end{table}
```

How can this table be squeezed into a A4 document?
Again: The goal is to move it slightly left, so that it extends to equal amounts of the left and right side outside the "main box" of the page, or whatever the thing determiing the margins is called.

The text (both on other, but also on the same page) should be unaffected by this.
I did manage to get something to happen using `\setlength{\hoffset}{-5mm}`, but this caused all sorts of trouble, mostly the whole page (and the ones following it) being shifted left.

## TL;DR

I want to center a `tabular`-in-`table`-table despite it overflowing the page slightly,
and leave the rest of the document unaffected.

Comment: \hspace*{-10pt} before the tabular will move it to the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `\makebox[\linewidth][c]{…}` to center (horizontal material like a `tabular`) independent from the width:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}  
  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[pos]{r|cccccccccccccccccccc}
      1x & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 10 \\
    \end{tabular}%
  }
  \caption{Lots of numbers}
  \label{tab:numbers}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}  
  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[pos]{r|cccccccccc}
      1x & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 \\
    \end{tabular}%
  }
  \caption{Less numbers}
  \label{tab:lessnumbers}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: two tables, one wider than text, one smaller, both centered]

Note: The `%` chars are important to not add extra spaces, that could otherwise unbalance the centering.

Answer (score 0):

Babsed on [cabohah](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/672022/31283)'s answer (+1 for a solution with `\mbox`es), I'd like to add two suggestions to OP.

**Caption**
If a table exceeds page boundaries, it might be desired that a long caption would take the same width as the table. I would leave a default `justification` perhaps with hanging format for longer captions because (1) short captions get centred and (2) spanning multiple lines get justified by default.

**Bad boxes**
This table gives a warning about bad boxes, which I would suppress locally by adding `\hfuzz` inside the `table` environment. If LaTeX warns again, it will mean there are issues something else in the document.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}

\newsavebox\widetab


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \hfuzz=\linewidth   %<--- suppress warning about bad boxes
  \captionsetup{format=hang,position=bottom,skip=6pt}
  \sbox\widetab{%
    \begin{tabular}[pos]{@{}r|*{20}{c}@{}}
      1x & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 10 \\
    \end{tabular}}%
  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{\usebox\widetab}

  \hspace{-0.5\dimexpr\wd\widetab-\linewidth}%
  \begin{minipage}{\wd\widetab}
    \caption{Lots of numbers. \kant[1][1]}\label{tab:numbers}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]